# Where can i find a Data.mdb in ObjectBox?

Tags: android, objectbox

How can I found a data.mdb, generated by ObjectBox in a Android project?
I'm trying to ship an android app with a pre-populated ObjectBox, but I cant find it

Comment: What do you mean by generated?

If you deploy your app to a device, assuming you did not change the default directory, the database will be created in the files dir for that app. This is likely in `/data/data/<package_name>`. For details see https://android.stackexchange.com/a/47951

Comment: Forgot: also have a look at https://docs.objectbox.io/faq#can-i-ship-my-app-with-a-pre-built-database

Comment: I use an Android smartphone to debug and to have access to this path, the root is required.

Comment: Try using the Device File Explorer in Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer